# How to run tox -e myenv against other environments?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, automated-tests, pytest, tox

Is it possible in tox to have `tox -e hello` trigger the hello environment and run on the global envlist?

Running `tox` runs correctly against py2 and py3.

Running `tox -e hello` only runs against py3.

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = py{27,37}

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    !py27: mock
commands =
    {envpython} --version

; How to run this hello against the complete envlist?
[testenv:hello]
envlist = py{27,37}
commands =
    echo hello
```

It seems this is expected behavior in some way, but I can't figure out how to use tox to solve the problem apart from making a bunch of tox files: I want to have different command entry points to tox. For instance, just run the unit tests against `py27`, just run the unit tests against `py{27,37}`, just run the integration tests against `py27-{libA,libB}`, etc.

Maybe it's just an anti pattern that you ~can use tox -e this way for a single environment, but it breaks envlist?

Do I just have to make another tox.ini then? That seems very clumsy given how flexible and re-use oriented everything else is about tox. I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main things to understand here:

1. `envlist` is a [global setting](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html?highlight=envlist#tox-global-settings) in the `[tox]` section. Defining it in `[testenv:hello]` has no effect
2. `envlist` defines or generates a list of `env` names. This can be done either statically by providing a simple comma separated list or - like you did - generating the list combinatorically from factors provided via special syntax `{...}`. The result in **both** cases is a list of environment names that will then be executed in separated `virtualenvs` / `venvs`.

So to make it perfectly clear: in the end an `envlist` is a simple list of `env` names - nothing else. What is being done with those names (or their parts (a.k.a. *factors*)) is happening during execution in `envs`.

All of these these environments are executed if you call tox **without** `-e`. In your example you are [generating an envlist](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#generative-envlist) with the `{<factorX>,<factorY>}` syntax which is based on the same principle like provided by commandline shells. If you ask for the generated environments in your tox config the result will be:

```
$ tox -a

py27-hello
py37-hello
hello
```

This might show already that things are a bit off in your config, because I don't think you want an unqualified `hello` env.

So what you are doing by generatively creating the envlist and statically providing the `hello` testenv using the `[testenv:hello]` syntax is mixing those in a way that then doesn't yield the result you would like to have.

So let's adapt your `tox.ini` to get rid of that unnecessary statically defined `testenv:hello`. We also get rid of the local `envlist` key as it had no effect anyway. It did not throw an error because arbitrarily named keys in `envs` are explicitly allowed and sometimes useful.

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = py{27,37}-hello

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    !py27: mock
# do not warn that echo is a command not in the venv
whitelist_externals = echo
commands =
    {envpython} --version
    hello: echo hello
```

To make sure that the hello command is only run, when the env has a `hello` factor you can use `<factor>[,<factor>]: <some command>` to specify what should be run if the env name contains a certain [factor](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#factors-and-factor-conditional-settings) (which are name parts separated by `-`) 
is generating a list of environment names that then serve as information for the concrete environments being executed.

If I call `tox -a` again on the changed ini I get:

```
py27-hello
py37-hello
```

Now I can ask for complete envs or only for factors by calling e.g. `tox -e py27-hello` or even `tox -e hello` which will then use the basepython and do everything that fits the factor.

To get more insight what is going on, you can display the completely resolved configuration for all environments, wich looks somethin like this:

```
$ tox --showconfig

[testenv:py27-hello]
  envdir          = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/py27-hello
  setenv          = SetenvDict: {'PYTHONHASHSEED': '1602746531', 'TOX_ENV_NAME': 'py27-hello', 'TOX_ENV_DIR': '/home/ob/do/play/.tox/py27-hello'}
  basepython      = python2.7
  description     = 
  envtmpdir       = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/py27-hello/tmp
  envlogdir       = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/py27-hello/log
  downloadcache   = None
  changedir       = /home/ob/do/play
  args_are_paths  = True
  skip_install    = False
  ignore_errors   = False
  recreate        = False
  passenv         = {'TOX_REPORTER_TIMESTAMP', 'TOX_WORK_DIR', 'TMPDIR', 'TOX_PARALLEL_ENV', 'LANGUAGE', 'LANG', 'PATH', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'PIP_INDEX_URL'}
  whitelist_externals = []
  platform        = .*
  sitepackages    = False
  alwayscopy      = False
  pip_pre         = False
  usedevelop      = False
  install_command = ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '{opts}', '{packages}']
  list_dependencies_command = ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'freeze']
  deps            = [pytest]
  commands        = [['/home/ob/do/play/.tox/py27-hello/bin/python', '--version'], ['echo', 'hello']]
  commands_pre    = []
  commands_post   = []
  ignore_outcome  = False
  extras          = []
  depends         = ()
  parallel_show_output = False
[testenv:py37-hello]
  envdir          = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/py37-hello
  setenv          = SetenvDict: {'PYTHONHASHSEED': '1602746531', 'TOX_ENV_NAME': 'py37-hello', 'TOX_ENV_DIR': '/home/ob/do/play/.tox/py37-hello'}
  basepython      = python3.7
  description     = 
  envtmpdir       = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/py37-hello/tmp
  envlogdir       = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/py37-hello/log
  downloadcache   = None
  changedir       = /home/ob/do/play
  args_are_paths  = True
  skip_install    = False
  ignore_errors   = False
  recreate        = False
  passenv         = {'TOX_REPORTER_TIMESTAMP', 'TOX_WORK_DIR', 'TMPDIR', 'TOX_PARALLEL_ENV', 'LANGUAGE', 'LANG', 'PATH', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'PIP_INDEX_URL'}
  whitelist_externals = []
  platform        = .*
  sitepackages    = False
  alwayscopy      = False
  pip_pre         = False
  usedevelop      = False
  install_command = ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '{opts}', '{packages}']
  list_dependencies_command = ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'freeze']
  deps            = [pytest, mock]
  commands        = [['/home/ob/do/play/.tox/py37-hello/bin/python', '--version'], ['echo', 'hello']]
  commands_pre    = []
  commands_post   = []
  ignore_outcome  = False
  extras          = []
  depends         = ()
  parallel_show_output = False
[testenv:hello]
  envdir          = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/hello
  setenv          = SetenvDict: {'PYTHONHASHSEED': '1602746531', 'TOX_ENV_NAME': 'hello', 'TOX_ENV_DIR': '/home/ob/do/play/.tox/hello'}
  basepython      = /usr/bin/python
  description     = 
  envtmpdir       = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/hello/tmp
  envlogdir       = /home/ob/do/play/.tox/hello/log
  downloadcache   = None
  changedir       = /home/ob/do/play
  args_are_paths  = True
  skip_install    = False
  ignore_errors   = False
  recreate        = False
  passenv         = {'TOX_REPORTER_TIMESTAMP', 'TOX_WORK_DIR', 'TMPDIR', 'TOX_PARALLEL_ENV', 'LANGUAGE', 'LANG', 'PATH', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'PIP_INDEX_URL'}
  whitelist_externals = []
  platform        = .*
  sitepackages    = False
  alwayscopy      = False
  pip_pre         = False
  usedevelop      = False
  install_command = ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '{opts}', '{packages}']
  list_dependencies_command = ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'freeze']
  deps            = [pytest, mock]
  commands        = [['/home/ob/do/play/.tox/hello/bin/python', '--version'], ['echo', 'hello']]
  commands_pre    = []
  commands_post   = []
  ignore_outcome  = False
  extras          = []
  depends         = ()
  parallel_show_output = False
```

Comment: This is perfect and what I needed!! The `hello: echo hello` part is the critical piece I was fumbling for and the correct way to do it. And thanks for the showconfig, that is very helpful!!